# The final step of proving Kuratowski’s Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, planar-graphs

Recently when I read the proof of the Kuratowski’s Theorem, I was *stuck at the final step* where it States 4 cases (Since this proof uses many lemmas, it is difficult to give one context related with lemmas in the question box).

I read this [lecture_1 p7](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Emradclif/teaching/228F16/Kuratowski.pdf) which is same as this [video 12:10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOnY6eZi2E8), but they both don't show why there are only these 4 cases

> We claim, without proof (although you should be able to prove this!) that the impedimentary structure
> inside C must take one of the forms illustrated in Figure 8

This [paper p10,11](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2017/REUPapers/Xu,Yifan.pdf) seems to drop the top-right case in the lecture_1.

It is trivial to check these 4 cases are **impedimentary** structures which avoids $uv$ to be outside so that $G$ can be planar which is contradiction

> Now, it must be the case that we could not have placed the path P interior to C, otherwise we would
> do so and thus be able to include the edge uv **exterior** to C. Hence, there must be some **impedimentary**
> structure inside C blocking us from drawing P in the interior.

Q:

How to prove that there is only the 4 cases listed in lecture_1 possible to be the impedimentary structure?

Comment: I tried to classify it by the number of vertices on the cycle before. Although it can works well, it may will have five different cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but then if indexed from $1$ to $4$ when clockwise from the top left, 1,2 will have 2 more vertices on the cycle $v_i$ and 3,4 will add none. There is only 2 cases.

Comment: I’m really sorry that I cannot image the 2 cases you mention. My original idea was separate the cases of how many vertices on the cycle C, and then divide the cases of how many vertices on C is on u v or $x_1$ or $x_2$. You can think that the condition  on this four points are symmetric.

Comment: Fine. Thanks anyway.